# Application hangs with Full page heap enabled

Tags: crash-dumps, heap-corruption, application-verifier

My Application crashes while closing a Dialog. I tried to debug the code and could not make any good conclusions from that. I took crash dumps and analyzed using the Debug Diag tool and got the report that it could be a Heap corruption in MSVBVM60.dll. 
As a next step, I tried enabling the Full Page heap but my application completely hangs. I am aware that enabling Full page heap would bring down the performance and can make the application not Responsive. This exactly happened with my application as well.
I tried with Normal Page heap, but still did not get any good info.
I tried setting in the Application verifier and also in the GFlags.
I tried for Heap tail and other options but could not really conclude the root cause.
I Tried for the specific image and not the whole machine.
Is it possible to take Full page heap by increasing the RAM of my machine?
Or is there any thing that I can do to get Full page heap? Please suggest.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. I have Intel Xeon processors (2 core) and  RAM is 16 GB, Win 7 x64 OS

Comment: Try running your application under [Application Verifier](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028).  It catches some subtle problems.

Comment: I have already tried with Application Verifier. Even in this case, it did not help me much. I am now in need to take full Page heap dump. Could just increasing the RAM will it make it possible to get the full page heap?